# I can't activate Wordpress plugins anymore

Tags: wordpress, debugging, plugins

For a reason I can't explain, I cannot activate plugins anymore on my Wordpress website, let's call it MAIN.

The problem chronologically happened after wp_postmeta has crashed and was repaired (I do not know if there is a link).

To give more informations:

- My website is part of a Wordpress Multisite. I can activate plugins at the Network admin level and for others websites inside the network, but not on MAIN
- I deactivate all plugins, put the twenty-twenty theme and I still can't activate plugins at the MAIN level
- I checked the whole database to see if some other tables were crashed
- I cleaned old datas and plugins
- I manage to force-activate plugin on MAIN level with code inside functions.php
- I tried to switch from Chrome to Firefox with no effect
- I can modify and save my user profile. I can post articles too
- I checked file permissions and nothing seems weird

When I try to activate plugin on MAIN level via the back-office, no error is thrown, the page reloads and i get the message "plugin activated" though it is not.

While I don't attend you to find immediately the solution, what did I miss? And what test can I run to fix the bug?

Comment: What do you mean "MAIN level"? Do you mean via the dashboard for the first site of your multisite install? At any rate, plugin activation for multisite is done via the network dashboard. not the dashboard for any particular site including the first one.

Comment: MAIN is just the name of the website that bugs, inside the network of Wordpress Multisites.

With Wordpress Multisite, the network dashboard is indeed the place where you are able to upload plugin. But you have the choice to activate the plugins (or not) on subsite level.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.